# Day from date Scala

Tags: scala, date

I'd like to get the day from a date object as an integer. This is my code so far.

```
val dateString = "2015-11-24 23:23:09"
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s")
val date = format.parse(dateString)
print(date) # this gives Tue Nov 24 23:23:09 CST 2015
```

Now, from date, I want to get the day of the month as an integer. How do I do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the Java Calendar class (although I would recommend moving over to the Joda library if you are doing much serious work with dates/times):

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.setTime(date)
val dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked very well. Is there a way to add/subtract days,months,years etc from a time? For example "2015-06-07 23:00:00" +7 hours will become "2015-06-08 06:00:00"

Comment: @SamuelKajah The `Calendar` class provides methods for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: This Answer is now outmoded, using troublesome old date-time classes that have been legacy for years, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2015-11-24 23:23:09".replace( " " , "T" ) 
).getDayOfMonth()
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

Using Java syntax here as I don't know Scala. Note that java.time uses [immutable objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Convert your string to comply with ISO 8601 standard format with a `T` in the middle.

```
String input = "2015-11-24 23:23:09".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse as an `LocalDateTime` as your input lacks any time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

[Interrogate for the day of month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getDayOfMonth--).

```
int dom = ldt.getDayOfMonth() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Joda,

```
org.joda.time.DateTime.now().getDayOfMonth()
```

or equivalently,

```
import java.util.Date
new org.joda.time.DateTime(new Date()).getDayOfMonth
```

Comment: I've seen this Joda stuff. But when ever I try to import it gives an error. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The Joda-Time project has been in maintenance mode for years now, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.